# NewAzureRmVM: Required parameter 'networkProfile' is missing (null)

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

So I have been trying to create a VM from Linux VHD and getting this error.
Following this
https://pebkac.io/2016/10/mikrotik-chr-in-azure-part-two/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dinesh has resolved the problem, per comments on [this](https://pebkac.io/2016/04/mikrotik-chr-in-microsoft-azure-arm).

It seems that the NIC creation may have been long running.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error, please ensure `NIC Interface` is created successful.

```
$InterfaceName = "nic-chr-test"

$Interface = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $InterfaceName -ResourceGroupName
```

You could the result of `$Interface`, if this is `NULL`, please create NIC firstly.

Also, you could try to use this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd) or scripts in this 
template.

Answer (score 0):

Add the NW interface for the VM

```
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.id
```

Answer (score 0):

[Worked for me , needed to add the network interface to vm. Here is the cmdlet

Assuming you already created $nic - network interface earlier

PS C:\azure> $vm = Add-azurermvmnetworkinterface -vm $vm -id $nic.id

PS C:\azure> new-azurermvm -resourcegroupname $rgname -location $location -vm $vm